# Add different visualisation to individual facets of ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Following on from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656776/best-way-to-add-points-to-all-facets-in-ggplot2-in-r/62657077#62657077) how can change the 4th facet "unknown" to a `geom_ribbon` representation?

I would like to keep the first 3 plots of the facet as `geom_point`.

Example:

```r
## load example iris data
data(iris)

## relabel some points in the data as "unknown"
set.seed(1)
plot_data <- iris
ind <- sample(seq(nrow(iris)), 20)
plot_data$Species <- factor(plot_data$Species, c(levels(plot_data$Species), "unknown"))
plot_data[ind, "Species"] <- "unknown"

## add ids for each point and specifiy colour scheme
plot_data$id <- seq(nrow(plot_data))
cols <- c("pink", "yellow", "blue", "grey")

## make facet plot
g <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") 
g
```

This produces this
[image]

Thank you.

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.0        stringr_1.4.0        purrr_0.3.4          readr_1.3.1         
 [5] tidyr_1.1.0          tibble_3.0.1         tidyverse_1.3.0      plotly_4.9.2.1      
 [9] reshape2_1.4.4       ggplot2_3.3.1        circlize_0.4.9       shinyhelper_0.3.2   
[13] colorspace_1.4-1     colourpicker_1.0     shinythemes_1.1.2    DT_0.13             
[17] shiny_1.4.0.2        dplyr_1.0.0          pRoloc_1.29.0        BiocParallel_1.22.0 
[21] MLInterfaces_1.68.0  cluster_2.1.0        annotate_1.66.0      XML_3.99-0.3        
[25] AnnotationDbi_1.50.0 IRanges_2.22.2       MSnbase_2.14.2       ProtGenerics_1.20.0 
[29] S4Vectors_0.26.1     mzR_2.22.0           Rcpp_1.0.4.6         Biobase_2.48.0      
[33] BiocGenerics_0.34.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved by subsetting the data passed to the geoms like so:

Note: I also added names to the color vector for easy use and to get the right colors when using `scale_fill_manual`.

```r
## load example iris data
data(iris)

library(ggplot2)

## relabel some points in the data as "unknown"
set.seed(1)
plot_data <- iris
ind <- sample(seq(nrow(iris)), 20)
plot_data$Species <- factor(plot_data$Species, c(levels(plot_data$Species), "unknown"))
plot_data[ind, "Species"] <- "unknown"

## add ids for each point and specifiy colour scheme
plot_data$id <- seq(nrow(plot_data))
cols <- c("pink", "yellow", "blue", "grey")
cols <- setNames(cols, levels(plot_data$Species))
## make facet plot
g <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = subset(plot_data, Species != "unknown"), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = subset(plot_data, Species == "unknown"), aes(x = Sepal.Length, ymin = Sepal.Width - .2, ymax = Sepal.Width + .2, fill = Species)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") 
g
```

[image]